# Python looping in list with if condition not working

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop in a list called sizeList and check a condition. The code is not returning the right values. Anyone knows what the problem might be?

```
overAvg = 0
overTre = 0

avgSize = np.mean(sizeList)

for a in sizeList:
    if a >= avgSize:
        overAvg += 1

treshold = raw_input("Enter Size Treshold: ")

for t in sizeList:
    if t >= treshold:
        overTre += 1


print overAvg
print overTre

for key, value in pktDict.iteritems():
    sizeValue = [value]
    sizeList.append(sizeValue)
```

Working Code:

```
for key, value in pktDict.iteritems():
        sizeValue = value
        sizeList.append(sizeValue)

avgSize = np.mean(sizeList)

for a in sizeList: 
   if a >= avgSize:
       overAvg += 1

treshold = int(raw_input("Enter Size Treshold: "))

for t in sizeList:
    if t >= treshold:
        overTre += 1

print overAvg
print overTre
```

Comment: What is your expected output? And what output you're getting currently?

Comment: Could You also post example values of sizeList and what You have and expect as output?

Comment: I'm guessing it might be stemming from not converting treshold to a number? treshold = float(raw_input("Enter Size Treshold: "))

Comment: the list contains over 2000 values which I extract from a .csv file

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the input size to `int`, otherwise it is comparing the lexical value rather than the numerical. Also, from the comment I see your list has a list of size 1 in each field, you need to flatten this (or initialize your list to be 1D in the first place):

```
import numpy as np
overAvg = 0
overTre = 0
sizeList = [[4],[7],[43],[5],[54],[7],[4],[5]] # only formatted like this because OP's list is
sizeList = [item[0] for item in sizeList]
avgSize = np.mean(sizeList)

for a in sizeList:
  if a >= avgSize:
    overAvg += 1

treshold = int(raw_input("Enter Size Treshold: "))

for t in sizeList:
  if t >= treshold:
    overTre += 1


print overAvg
print overTre
```

Result:

```
Enter Size Treshold: 5
2
6
```

In your code, you're creating a list with only one item each iteration, while you should be doing this:

```
for key, value in pktDict.iteritems():
    sizeList.append(value)
```

Comment: I have tried this, even if I enter a threshold value higher than those which I know are in the list overTre is still incrementing.

Maybe there is a problem with how I am creating the list?

Comment: @LukeGatt what does the list look like?

Comment: something like this when I print the list, http://gyazo.com/17bd47f3cca6fc2cbc231d5eebc1f80b

Comment: @LukeGatt I see, I've updated my answer now. If you could post the code where your list is created, I could help you avoid the nested list problem altogether.

Comment: I have found the problem causing the values to become [ ], sizeValue = [value] should be sizeValue = value

The code is working now thanks for your help I was looking in the wrong direction.